# Industry Icon with NonLinear or CompanionAd in VAST 4.2

Tags: vast

It says 'This feature is only offered for Linear Ads because icons can be easily inserted in NonLinear ads and companion creative using existing features.' in VAST 4.2 document. But I don't know how it looks like.
I try this

```
                        <NonLinear id="GDFP" width="480" height="70" minSuggestedDuration="00:00:05" scalable="true" maintainAspectRatio="true">
                            <StaticResource creativeType="image/png">
                                <![CDATA[https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKDTwKyTLBDgAxhGMghR083HVMUH8w]]>
                            </StaticResource>
                            <NonLinearClickThrough>
                                <![CDATA[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click]]>
                            </NonLinearClickThrough>
                            <NonLinearClickTracking>
                                <![CDATA[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click]]>
                            </NonLinearClickTracking>
                        </NonLinear>
                        <NonLinear>
                            <Icon program="DAA" width="77" height="15" xPosition="right" yPosition="top" offset="00:00:00">
                                <StaticResource creativeType="image/png"><![CDATA[https://s.aolcdn.com/ads/adchoices.png]]></StaticResource>
                            </Icon>
                        </NonLinear>
```

and it do not work.

I also try this

```
<NonLinear id="GDFP" width="480" height="70" minSuggestedDuration="00:00:05" scalable="true" maintainAspectRatio="true">
                            <StaticResource creativeType="image/png">
                                <![CDATA[https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKDTwKyTLBDgAxhGMghR083HVMUH8w]]>
                            </StaticResource>
                            <NonLinearClickThrough>
                                <![CDATA[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click]]>
                            </NonLinearClickThrough>
                            <NonLinearClickTracking>
                                <![CDATA[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click]]>
                            </NonLinearClickTracking>
                        </NonLinear>
                        <NonLinear program="DAA" width="77" height="15" xPosition="right" yPosition="top" offset="00:00:00">
                            <StaticResource creativeType="image/png"><![CDATA[https://s.aolcdn.com/ads/adchoices.png]]></StaticResource>
                        </NonLinear>
```

and it do not work, `NonLinear` tag seems do not allow `program`, `xPosition`, `yPosition` attribute.

Can you give a sample?